# checkbox onchange firing twice

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

I'm attaching an `onchange` event on checkboxes like this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='auswahl[]']").on("change", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("id") + ' ' + $("label[for='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']").text() + $(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

The checkboxes look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auswahl[]" id="aus_nunatsiaqnews_ca"><label for="aus_nunatsiaqnews_ca" title="Canada">Nunatsiaq News</label>
```

Unfortunately the event is firing twice. When I isolate the code given above and put it on a test page everything is fine and the event is firing only once.
Need help.

Comment: When you are attaching the event handler?

Comment: it does trigger once https://jsfiddle.net/gkz5owms/ . I think somehow you are attaching "onchange" two times.

Comment: @Satpal: I'm attaching it at the bottom of the page, after the checkboxes have been defined. No onload or document-ready being used.

Comment: @esertbas: I know about this. I wrote "When I isolate the code given above and put it on a test page everything is fine and the event is firing only once."

Comment: @Sempervivum you should give full code to resolve it, it can really hard to find out without code :)

Comment: The code is too long to post. In my initial posting I posted a link to my page but it seems to be lost. Here it is again: [link](http://ulrichbangert.de/div/webdesign/javascript/Medienauswahl.html) Watch the console in order to see the error.

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when a control with an "onClick" event is nested inside another control with an "onClick" event. Clicking one of the elements triggers the events for both elements since there is no way of knowing which of them you wanted to click.
fortunately, this can be prevented in Javascript. in the HTML, pass the "$event" parameter to the function that handles the click event like so:

```html
onClick="myFunc($event)"
```

and then, in "myFunc" use "stopPropagation" as such:

```js
myFunc($event) {
  // ... some code ... //
  $event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: @Sempervivum if this solved your problem, please accept it as an answer.