# Todo list application, how to cancel the delete action when unchecked the checkbox during the time delay?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

front end is a form with checkbox to submit when click the checkbox:

```
<form class="" action="/delete" method="post">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%=newListItems[i].id%>" onChange="this.form.submit()">
    <p><%=  newListItems[i].name  %></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

backend(express nodejs)

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res) {
  const checkedID = req.body.checkbox;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (checkedID != undefined) {
      Item.findByIdAndDelete(checkedID, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

The click and unclick actions execute the post method twice, so the if else statement does not work as expected.

Comment: I can't produce your problem, but there I've found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202446/checkbox-onchange-firing-twice/44042574)

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution using clearTimeout().

```
 app.post("/delete", function(req, res) {
  const checkedID = req.body.checkbox;
    if (checkedID != undefined) {
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      Item.findByIdAndDelete(checkedID, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);
      res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```